# Script not returning 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I have a PHP script that does some validation, and if the validation is off, it should return 404. But it doesn't.

Here is the beginning of the script:

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';
include '../global.php';
include '../utils/api/problems.php';
include '../utils/api/suggested_solutions.php';
include '../utils/api/attempted_solutions.php';
include '../utils/api/categories.php';

$problem_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["problem_id"]);

// Get member_id from session
$member_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

// Validate the call
if ( empty ( $problem_id ) || !isset ( $problem_id ) || !is_numeric ( $problem_id ) )
{
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 

    // Send me an email with the error:
    $from = "from: problem_url_error@problemio.com";  
    $to_email_address = 'my_email';
    $error_subject = 'Error happened when getting problem_id from request';
    $contents = 'Error in problem.php - here is the referer: '.$referer;

    //mail($to_email_address, $error_subject, $contents, $from);    

    error_log ( ".......error validating problem id in problem.php");
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
}
```

But for some reason, this does not return a 404 - any idea why?

Thanks!!

Comment: what **does** it return ? a blank page by any chance ?

Comment: Have you turned display_errors on? Don't you get any errors about headers already sent, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header is called status:

```
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```

**EDIT:**
Now I see your approach *should* work as well, study the header [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) if you meet the requirements to use `header("HTTP/xxx ...")`, there are some limitations.

Answer (score 3):

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Should be sufficient according to the docs - the Status header is used when using FastCGI - [Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

What you will get is a blank page, you can add content like this :

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo "<h1>404 Not Found</h1>";
echo "The page that you have requested could not be found.";
```

Comment: for some reason, none of the headers work. I am not sure why. :(

Comment: Perhaps some other headers are sent already - see what `headers_sent()` returns just before you set your headers